# Is it okay to use an infinite loop to constantly check the Connection to a Server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, infinite-loop

I am writing my first Angular App today. Now i want to check the connection to a Server. If its offline, a Screen Should appear that says something like "Youre offline, but you neet a Connection". I have a JavaScript Function that is doing this very good. But right now, I can only check my Connection Status when i click a specific Button. But I want to check the Connection constantly, so if the Connection shuts down, the Screen appears instantly.

I am programming since 2 years now and in the past i heard the sentence "dont use infinite loops" or "never use infinite loops" etc. very often.

My Question is, would it be okay to use an infinite loop in this situation? Or is there another workaround?

My Code is pretty Simple:

```
var isOnline;
function testIfOnline() {
    if(navigator.onLine) {

        if (!isOnline) {
            hideConnectionView();
        }

        isOnline = true;
    } else {
        if (isOnline) {
            console.log("Die Verbindung zum Server wurde unterbrochen!");
        } else {
            console.log("Es konnte keine Verbindung zum Server aufgebaut werden!");
        }

        isOnline = false;

        //Restlicher Code:

        showConnectionView();

    }
}
```

2. Question:
   Is there a specific rule that says, when a Infinite Loop is allowed to use or something?

Comment: "Allowed" by whom? When people say there are "rules" like this, they don't mean "you'll be punished by some authority for doing this", they mean "it is bad idea to do this". Rather than looking for _when_ it's a bad idea, you should try to understand _why_ it's a bad idea; then you can make your own decisions about the tradeoffs that might apply in your particular case.

Comment: consider using events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events

Comment: Infinite loops are used all the time in other languages, but polling a server in Javascript isn't what I'd use one for (you'll block the main/only thread). Use `setInterval`, that's what it's for. Or possibly websockets, although that's a more complex topic.

Comment: A few other Programmers here said it. I am technically allowed to use them, but they said, that I should try to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: @JaredSmith yeah I would have done it with Web Socket API

Comment: @yama_HD depends on *why* you need to know, if all you need to know is whether the user's device is online or offline then mchl18's answer is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not okay :D Calling a function endlessly is in this case not needed and overkill because there are events.

consider this:

```
import {fromEvent, merge} from 'rxjs'

merge(
   fromEvent(window, 'online'),
   fromEvent(window, 'offline'),
).subscribe(
  () => {
    const condition = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";
    console.log(condition);
  }
)
```

EDIT: To combat the fact that this does not work when unplugging the machine we can extend it like this:

```
import { interval, merge, fromEvent } from 'rxjs'; 
import { mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';


merge(
  fromEvent(window, 'online'),
  fromEvent(window, 'offline'),
  interval(1000),
).pipe(
  mapTo(navigator.onLine),
).subscribe(
  online => { 
    const condition = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";
    console.log(condition);
  }
)
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-angvhp?file=index.ts)

Comment: This is the 'right' way to do it.

Comment: I am pretty new to Angular, I would consider that this Code should be written in the `app.component.ts` or in the `app.module.ts`. As i said, my first time working with Angular :D

Comment: What if internet is working but the server is down? 
a offline event is useful in all is glory but a failed connection to the server should be catch at the point when you tried to call the server. I think this short snippet should be written in vanilla javascript without rxjs

Comment: @yama_HD no code in modules, should be in a component, or better, a service.

Comment: @Endless that is a different question but there is a retry and catchError operator

Comment: @mchl18 The Code you posted works fine when I set the online status in the Chrome Developer Tools to online/offline. But when I remove the Network Cable from my Laptop, it doesnt work.

Comment: @yama_HD which browser?

Comment: @yama_HD I extended the code to periodically check

Answer (score -1):

you can use nodemon to run your server continuously [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)